# NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID cloudflare zero trust application when warp enabled

Tags: cloudflare, cloudflare-zero-trust

I have set up a self hosted app in Cloudflare zero trust, it points to my server that has a tunnel installed on it, and the hostname is configured in the DNS settings to point to the tunnel address.

If I do **NOT** have the cloudflare zero trust warp enabled, everything works as expected, I can access the self hosted app using the hostname.

However, if I **enable** to warp client, so that my connection is “protected” I get a certificate error when trying to access the application via the hostname.
Does anyone know what could be causing this and how I can resolve it?

I want  my users to have WARP enabled and be able to access my self hosted app.
TIA!